# Eclipse Ditto bad gateway

Tags: sandbox, eclipse-ditto, eclipse-digital-twin

I'm using Eclipse Ditto's sandbox for a university project and it has given me as result 502 Bad Gateway for days (almost a week) for each command I tried and I can't do basically anything in the dashboard. Are Eclipse Ditto's servers Down or is my problem?
If is ditto's fault are there any solution other then deploying docker and using ditto in local?

P.S: my team mate is experiencing the same issue

Answer (score 1):

The Eclipse Ditto sandbox was offline - it is not maintained as "always available" instance, see also the [warning disclaimer](https://www.eclipse.org/ditto/sandbox.html) on the project site.

I would strongly recommend on running your own instance, a university surely has machines or free credits on public cloud providers to start a VM.

Comment: So you suggest deploying docker and running it locally?

Comment: just installing docker and running it locally, yes